# Weird compiler optimization/behavior regarding a "for" loop without a body in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays, compiler-construction, for-loop

I have the following C array of `NSString *`:

```
static NSString *const OrderByValueNames[] = {@"None",@"Added",@"Views",@"Rating",@"ABC",@"Meta"};
```

Now, I want to check the length of this array at runtime so I wrote the following method:

```
NSInteger LengthOfArray(NSString *const array[])
{
    NSInteger length = 0;
    // For Loop Without a body!
    for (length = 0; array[length] != nil; length++);
    return length;
}
```

Now, when I run this code at `debug` configuration, everything is fine and the function returns the right result.

**BUT** as soon as I switch to `release` configuration and run it again, the program freezes at the for loop. After 10 seconds of the loop being executed, iOS kills the app for not responding. Weird.

Now, if I add body to the loop, like that:

```
for (length = 0; array[length] != nil; length++)
{
    NSLog(@"%d",length);
}
```

Then it's working fine **even in release mode**.

Giving the loop an **empty body**, like that:

```
for (length = 0; array[length] != nil; length++){}
```

Still freezes in release mode.

My guess is that there is a compiler optimization when running in release mode, but what exactly?!

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it even possible to count the number of elements in a C array in this way?

Comment: @taskinoor Apparently it is... Do you know another way?

Comment: As far as I understand about C array that `array[length]` will contain some garbage value which may not equal to nil. No, I don't know any way to count the number of elements in a C array unless you have inserted some special value at end yourself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C-style arrays are not nil-terminated by default. If you want to check the length this way, you need to add the terminator yourself.

```
static NSString *const OrderByValueNames[] =
   {@"None",@"Added",@"Views",@"Rating",@"ABC",@"Meta",nil};
```

A much better way to find the length is simply this:

```
length = sizeof(OrderByValueNames) / sizeof(OrderByValueNames[0]);
```

(Note that this trick doesn't work if you pass the array into a function, since it then degenerates into a pointer.)

Comment: Walking off the end of the array is **undefined behaviour**. This means that literally anything can happen. So whatever does happen is within the scope of the standard.

Comment: @GrahamBorland note that `NSString*` is an `id` type, so using `nil` is correct.

Comment: @GrahamBorland the sizeof way returns the wrong result (always 1), any idea why?

Comment: Probably because you are passing the array into a function to calculate the length. You can't do that, see my warning in the answer.

Comment: @GrahamBorland You definitely KNOW c. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Your `OrderByValueNames` array doesn't contain a `nil` element. No wonder you can't find one! Walking off the end of the array like that will result in undefined behaviour. If you want to mark the end of the array with `nil`, you'll have to add it manually.

By the way, if you'd like to know the length of a fixed size C array, you can do this:

```
length = sizeof(OrderByValueNames)/sizeof(OrderByValueNames[0]);
```

This doesn't work for function parameters, though, as those are just pointers!

Comment: It's returning the wrong result... Any idea why? (It returns 1)

Comment: @AvrahamShukron as I said, you can't do this to function parameters, as they are pointers and therefore don't contain size information.